# How to add fill color in highcharts data series

Tags: javascript, dynamic, highcharts

I need to fill the color of data series dynamically based on the variable ( left , right , center ) from my code.

I have attached my code and expected output:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var left = [
  [4, 7],
  [9, 2]
];
var right = [
   [2, 2],
   [9, 9]
];

var center = [
        [4,5.5],
        [10,5.5] 
];

 Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
  events: {
   load: function () {
     const xAxis = this.xAxis[0]
     const yAxis = this.yAxis[0]

     const leftBottom = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(right[0][0]),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(right[0][1])
     }

     const leftTop = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(left[0][0]),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(left[0][1])
     }

     const rightBottom = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(left[1][0]),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(left[1][1])
     }

     const rightTop = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(right[1][0]),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(right[1][1])
     }

    const leftMiddle = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(4),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(5.5)
     }

     const rightMiddle = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(10),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(5.5)
     }

     const leftTopMiddle = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(3.7),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(6.5)
     }

    const leftBottomMiddle = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(2.1),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(4)
     }




     const rightTopMiddle = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(9.8),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(8)
     }

     const rightBottomMiddle = {
       x: xAxis.toPixels(9.8),
       y: yAxis.toPixels(3)
     }





     const curveTopLeft = this.curveTopLeft = this.renderer.path().attr({
       d: `M ${leftMiddle.x} ${leftMiddle.y} Q ${leftTopMiddle.x} ${leftTopMiddle.y} ${leftTop.x} ${leftTop.y}`,
       'stroke-width': 2,
       stroke: 'red',
       zIndex: 99
     }).add()

       const curveBottomLeft = this.curveBottomLeft = this.renderer.path().attr({
      d: `M ${leftMiddle.x} ${leftMiddle.y} Q ${leftBottomMiddle.x} ${leftBottomMiddle.y} ${leftBottom.x} ${leftBottom.y}`,
       'stroke-width': 2,
       stroke: 'red',
       zIndex: 99
     }).add()


       const curveTopRight = this.curveTopRight = this.renderer.path().attr({
       d: `M ${rightMiddle.x} ${rightMiddle.y} Q ${rightTopMiddle.x} ${rightTopMiddle.y} ${rightTop.x} ${rightTop.y}`,
       'stroke-width': 2,
       stroke: 'red',
       zIndex: 99
     }).add()

       const curveBottomRight = this.curveBottomRight = this.renderer.path().attr({
      d: `M ${rightMiddle.x} ${rightMiddle.y} Q ${rightBottomMiddle.x} ${rightBottomMiddle.y} ${rightBottom.x} ${rightBottom.y}`,
       'stroke-width': 2,
       stroke: 'red',
       zIndex: 99
     }).add()


   }
 }
 },

  title: {
    text: ''
  },

   tooltip: {
     enabled: false
   },

   exporting: {
      enabled: false
   },

   credits: {
     enabled: false
   },


   plotOptions: {
     series: {
     pointStart: 1

   }
 },

  xAxis: {
   max: 10,
   min: 1,
   tickInterval: 1
 },

  yAxis: {
    max: 11,
    min: 0,
    tickInterval: 1,

  },
 series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: left
 }, {
   showInLegend: false,
   data: right
 },
  {
 showInLegend: false,
      marker: {
               enabled: true
     },
     data: center
 }],
 });
 });
```

And my expected output should look like below,

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide us a working jsfiddle link to check?

Comment: Please check this jsfiddle.net/r0j46wn6/18

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new path with no stroke but fill. The new path should be combined from the points you already defined.

```
const d = `M ${leftBottom.x} ${leftBottom.y} 
           Q ${leftBottomMiddle.x} ${leftBottomMiddle.y} ${leftMiddle.x} ${leftMiddle.y} 
           Q ${leftTopMiddle.x} ${leftTopMiddle.y} ${leftTop.x} ${leftTop.y} 
           L ${rightBottom.x} ${rightBottom.y} 
           Q ${rightBottomMiddle.x} ${rightBottomMiddle.y} ${rightMiddle.x} ${rightMiddle.y} 
           Q ${rightTopMiddle.x} ${rightTopMiddle.y} ${rightTop.x} ${rightTop.y} 
           Z`

const fillPath = this.renderer.path().attr({
  d: d,
  'stroke-width': 0,
  fill: '#b19cd9',
  zIndex: 1
}).add()
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/r0j46wn6/24/
[image: fill]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `.css()` method of your `this.renderer.path()` to set the fill style.

For example, Let's take the case of `curveTopRight` for what you can add that css as,

```
const curveTopRight = this.curveTopRight = this.renderer.path().css({
    color: '#c8bfe7',
    fill: '#c8bfe7'
 }).attr({
   d: `M ${rightMiddle.x} ${rightMiddle.y} Q ${rightTopMiddle.x} ${rightTopMiddle.y} ${rightTop.x} ${rightTop.y}`,
   'stroke-width': 2,
   stroke: 'red',
   zIndex: 99
 }).add()
```

However it is working only for the curved elements and not for the area's which are between the lines that you have drawn.

**Here is a partially working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/r0j46wn6/23/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for you reply. actually i want full area fill color

Comment: @Nisanth Yes, I understand, Filling the area which the lines create among themself is kind of undocumented. I'm trying it from my end. If you find any solution kindly update the post with your answer, so that some one might get benefited out of it.

Comment: Ya . Sure. If i get answer means i will post here.